# twitter bootstrap CSS mobile

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a CSS question.  I'm trying to use the Twitter bootstrap theme but I'm running into an issue when I scale my website down to mobile.

http://webodew.com/websites/testsite/

If I make my computer browser window smaller, the text at the top starts to go above the text below…making it unreadable.

Is this due to a wrong place of a  tag?  I have tried to play with it but I can't find the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your problem seems to be

```
.main-banner {
height:400px;
}
```

Replacing it with

```
.main-banner {
min-height:400px;
}
```

Will resolve the problem. At least it does on my end :)